# Split multiple column with awk

Tags: awk

I need to split a file with multiple columns that looks like this:

```
TCONS_00000001       q1:Ovary1.13|Ovary1.13.1|100|32.599877      q2:Ovary2.16|Ovary2.16.1|100|88.36
TCONS_00000002       q1:Ovary1.19|Ovary1.19.1|100|12.876644      q2:Ovary2.15|Ovary2.15.1|100|365.44
TCONS_00000003       q1:Ovary1.19|Ovary1.19.2|0|0.000000         q2:Ovary2.19|Ovary2.19.1|100|64.567
```

Output needed:

```
TCONS_00000001       Ovary1.13.1     32.599877      Ovary2.16.1     88.36
TCONS_00000002       Ovary1.19.1     12.876644      Ovary2.15.1     365.44
TCONS_00000003       Ovary1.19.2     0.000000       Ovary2.19.1     64.567
```

My attempt:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"}{split($2,two,"|");split($3,thr,"|");print $1,two[2],two[4],thr[2],thr[4]}' in.file
```

**Problem:**

I have many more columns to split like 2 and 3, I would like to find a shorter solutions than splitting every column one by one.

Comment: Would `cat in.file | tr '|' '\t' | awk `... help your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [Sundeep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48399312/5291015) is great, if you are planning for a redundant action on a set of records, suggest using a function and run it on each record.

I would write an `awk` script as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

function split_args(record) {
    n=split(record,split_array,"[:|]")
    return (split_array[3]"\t"split_array[n])
}

BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }

{
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
       $i=split_args($i)
    }
    print
}
```

and invoke it as

```
awk -f script.awk inputfile
```

An ugly command-line version of it would be

```
awk 'function split_args(record) {
         n=split(record,split_array,"[:|]")
         return (split_array[3]"\t"split_array[n])
     } 
     BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }    
     {
        for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
            $i=split_args($i)
        }
        print
     }
' newfile
```

Comment: @Sundeep: I do hope you stick to this than adding a incomprehensible answer in `perl` ;)

Comment: here ya go: `perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join "\t", $F[0], map{(split /[:|]/)[2,-1]} @F[1..$#F]'` :) first time doing something like this :D

Comment: @Sundeep: This one is easy, but I would never learn this constructs `map` and others, they seem to be never ending

Comment: yeah, unless you like tinkering with such things... but then I actually learned list-comprehension/map/lambda in python and then got to know about map/grep/etc in perl ;) now learning a bit in ruby, which has map too..

Answer (score 2):

```
$ # borrowing simplicity from @Inian's answer ;)
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
       {for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){split($i,a,/[:|]/); $i=a[3] "\t" a[5]}} 1' ip.txt
TCONS_00000001  Ovary1.13.1 32.599877   Ovary2.16.1 88.36
TCONS_00000002  Ovary1.19.1 12.876644   Ovary2.15.1 365.44
TCONS_00000003  Ovary1.19.2 0.000000    Ovary2.19.1 64.567

$ # previous solution which leaves tab character at end
$ awk -F'\t' '{printf "%s\t",$1;
             for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){split($i,a,/[:|]/); printf "%s\t%s\t",a[3],a[5]};
             print ""}' ip.txt
TCONS_00000001  Ovary1.13.1 32.599877   Ovary2.16.1 88.36   
TCONS_00000002  Ovary1.19.1 12.876644   Ovary2.15.1 365.44  
TCONS_00000003  Ovary1.19.2 0.000000    Ovary2.19.1 64.567
```